# Windows IoT Core reading value returned System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Single] instead of float

Tags: c#, async-await, raspberry-pi2, windowsiot

I am following Chris Pietschmann's Weather Station 3.0 tutorial for Raspberry Pi using the BME280 sensor at: https://www.hackster.io/23021/weather-station-v-3-0-b8b8bc.

In the MainPage he calls ReadTemperture (or any of the other registers of the sensor) to write out the returned values.

I get System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Single] in the Debug.Writeline() for all of the values... Temp, humidity, pressure and altitude.

I added a writeline inside the method and I get the correct value so I'm reading from the sensor...  I just can't return it back to the mainpage and read it.

Looks like I'm missing something in the async side?

Here's the MainPage:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace IoT_BME280_Temp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        DispatcherTimer _timer;


        const float seaLevelPressure = 1026.00f;  //was 1022.00
        BME280Sensor _bme280 = new BME280Sensor();

        public MainPage()

        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);


            await _bme280.Initialize();

            _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;

            _timer.Start();

        }

        private void _timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            try
            {
                var temp     = _bme280.ReadTemperature();
                Debug.WriteLine("Temp: {0} deg C", temp);  // Results in: Temp: System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Single] deg C
                var humidity = _bme280.ReadHumidity();
                var pressure = _bme280.ReadPressure();
                var altitude = _bme280.ReadAltitude(seaLevelPressure);
            } 
        catch
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Cannot read values from sensor...");
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is ReadTemprature() from the BME280Sensor class:

```
public async Task<float> ReadTemperature()
    {
        //Make sure the I2C device is initialized
        if (!init) await Begin();

        //Read the MSB, LSB and bits 7:4 (XLSB) of the temperature from the BME280 registers
        byte tmsb = ReadByte((byte)eRegisters.BME280_REGISTER_TEMPDATA_MSB);
        byte tlsb = ReadByte((byte)eRegisters.BME280_REGISTER_TEMPDATA_LSB);
        byte txlsb = ReadByte((byte)eRegisters.BME280_REGISTER_TEMPDATA_XLSB); // bits 7:4

        //Combine the values into a 32-bit integer
        Int32 t = (tmsb << 12) + (tlsb << 4) + (txlsb >> 4);

        //Convert the raw value to the temperature in degC
        double temp = BME280_compensate_T_double(t);
        Debug.WriteLine("Temp: {0} deg C", temp);  //  This results in the correct temperature value...

        //Return the temperature as a float value
        return (float)temp;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to await calls to async functions

Comment: Thanks @Abion47 I realized that a little too late...  Working through someone's code and was getting frustrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a `Task` because that's what `ReadTemperature` returns when you call it synchronously. To get the result of the task rather than the task itself, you need to call the method using `await` and change `_timer_Tick` to be `async` as well:

```
private async void _timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    try
    {
        var temp     = await _bme280.ReadTemperature();
        Debug.WriteLine("Temp: {0} deg C", temp);
        var humidity = _bme280.ReadHumidity();
        var pressure = _bme280.ReadPressure();
        var altitude = _bme280.ReadAltitude(seaLevelPressure);
    } 
    catch
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Cannot read values from sensor...");
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO, this is one of the good reasons not to just blindly use `var` for everything, but rather only for variables whose type is _glaringly self-evident_.  If the line read `Task<float> temp = _bme280.ReadTemperature();` the issue would stand out.  It's also a good reason to follow the widely-adopted convention of naming async methods `xxxxAsync()`; e.g. `ReadTemperatureAsync()` in this case.

Comment: @sellotape Well said. If the line were `int temp = _bme280.ReadTemperature();`, the problem would've been self-evident then as well, as the program would not even compile.